# How can I calculate the evolution of turnover in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

I can't share my dataset because it's private for the company where I'm having my intership at.
So my dataset contains 3 columns and about 11 209 000 rows:

1. Id: Bunch of ids, many of them are repetitive.
2. Date : 2018, 2017, 2016, 2015?
3. Turnover.

I have this formula that I want to calculate: Formu = [turnover[date 1] aka recent one / turnover[date2] aka the previous one ] - 1

But I'm having some issues calculating it, especially because I don't know how to manage to variate with the id and date at the same time. (And because I have a large number of rows..)
Thanks!

Comment: be more precise about your formula, what's the expected dataset you want ?

Comment: I want another column that shows the evolution of the turnover for every Id

Comment: turnover is float or int value ?

Comment: it's a float value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to calculate the difference between a given row and the row before.

If the rows are in chronological order, you could use `.diff()` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html#pandas.DataFrame.diff) after grouping by `id`.

```py
df['difference'] = df.groupby("id").turnover.diff()
```

Comment: maybe sort by descending order "Date" before to be sure

Comment: I made a mistake in the formula it's not minus but '/' then substract with 1

Comment: For percentage change you can use the `.pct_change()` [method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html#pandas.DataFrame.pct_change) instead. I think that's what you're after(?)